# Drop Down not shown in master page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a customized layout for master page.But drop down is not working in that.In the below image "Introduction" is the site ans "About us" is the sub site in it.But not shown
[image]

But in site setting it displays the drop down

[image]

Comment: What's the master page for your System Master Page ? And is it structural navigation for the Global Navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are using a Custom master page, you missed some code snippets for structural navigation, Better Compare the Seattle master page codes and Customize your master page, And make sure following code are there in your master page

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline" runat="server">-->
                                    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">-->
                                    <!--SPM:<Template_Controls>-->
                                    <!--SPM:<asp:SiteMapDataSource 
                ShowStartingNode="False"
                SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" 
                id="topSiteMap" 
                runat="server"
                StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>-->
                                    <!--SPM:</Template_Controls>-->
                                    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
                                    <a name="startNavigation">
                                    </a>
                                    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
                                    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu 
            ID="TopNavigationMenu" 
            Runat="server" 
            EnableViewState="false"
            DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
            AccessKey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&#62;"
            UseSimpleRendering="true"
            UseSeparateCss="false"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            StaticDisplayLevels="2"
            AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
            SkipLinkText=""/>-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```